# Item rating in Algolia Search

Tags: javascript, laravel-5.4, algolia

I am using Algolia in my web system and I really like this service. The only thing on which I am stuck is I want to show star rating of items, you can see picture attached below for more clarification.

I don't want rating widget. I have an attribute called rating that has float values like 3.54 etc. I am using Laravel 5.4

Image : `https://img42.com/Xad0J`

Algolia's Hits Widget

---

```
search.addWidget(
         data = instantsearch.widgets.hits({
          container: '#hits-container',
          hitsPerPage: 10,
          templates: {
           item: function(data) {
              return '<div class="row well_our well-sm_our"> <div class="col-md-3"> <img class="img-responsive" src="'+data.pic_path+'"> </div> <div class="col-md-6"> <div class="rest-list-heading"><a href="menu/'+data.id+'">'+data.name+'</a></div> <div class="rest-list-para text-justify">'+data.description+'</div> </div> <div class="col-md-3 rest-coulmn-3"> <div title="Rating : rating" id="rating'+data.id+'"></div> <input type="hidden" id="ratingOfRest'+data.id+'" value="rating"> <div class="rest-list-para1" align="center"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="reviewsModal('+data.id+')">'+data.reviews+'</a> <input type="hidden" id="restID'+data.id+'" value="id"></div> <div class="dotted-btn-rest" align="center"> <a href="menu/'+data.id+'"> View Menu</a> </div> </div> </div>';
            },
          }
        })
      );
```

Laravel Blade:

---

```
<div id="hits-container"></div>
```

Comment: for future reference, this was solved here: https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch.js/issues/2324

Comment: Great Help. You are best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do that you need to implement two things. One is a [transformData](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/v2/widgets-common-api.html#transformdata), that will let you process your floats into elements that can be used in the the template.

You can find an example for the [transformData of a star rating here](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch.js/blob/e78de702ed53798431493df6e966a53d749930d7/docgen/src/examples/media/search.js#L44-L50). The other is the template. You can find the star rating template [a little above](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch.js/blob/e78de702ed53798431493df6e966a53d749930d7/docgen/src/examples/media/search.js#L28) the transform data.